# Do all non-parametric statistical tests involve bootstrapping, simulation, or permutation test?

Tags: bootstrap, permutation-test, nonparametric

All of the non-parametric tests I learned about involved bootstrapping, simulation of large samples of some random variable, or permutation tests. Are there non-parametric tests without simulation or bootstrapping? Do any parametric methods used bootstrapping, generation and simulation of random variables, or permutation tests?

Are all permutations tests or bootstrapping non-parametric?

Comment: There is something called parametric bootstrap (basically you are sampling the residuals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikipedia page on [nonparametric statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonparametric_statistics) lists over 20 common nonparametric statistical tests, most of which *do not* involve permutation testing or bootstrapping. These tests were generally developed long before modern computational capabilities made bootstrapping and permutation testing realistically possible and even [before the relatively recent development of the bootstrap principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)#History).

These tests typically involve statistics whose distributions do not depend on the underlying probability distributions of the values that are being sampled. Some are based, for example, on comparing the [ranks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking#Ranking_in_statistics) of the observations between 2 sets of observations rather than the values themselves. Other tests take advantage of how [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) translate an ordered set of observations into an estimate of the underlying cumulative probability distribution. Then tests are done along the cumulative probability axis, based on the order statistics of a uniform probability distribution over [0,1], rather than on the observed data directly.